# Models that converged before aren't converging anymore in Keras

Tags: keras

I have two models with saved data that worked well previously but won't anymore.

First, it happened with one of my Jupyter notebooks. I can even load the saved model and weights that work. When I train more with the exact same model, the performance actually drops! 
For example, I get a dice coefficient of -.39 with my previous training when it worked. Now if I load the same model, weights, and data, it drops to -0.04. (Loss of -1 is perfect).

So I load one of my older notebooks with a different model and saved data that worked well. It doesn't converge to nearly as high of a performance as it did previously either.

However, I tried setting up a simple MNIST CNN classifier and it worked fine.

Is there any way for there to be persistent changes to occur so that the exact same code/data that performed well before no longer does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually just the random weights and incredible luck that I got good convergence the first three tries in a row while didn't most other times afterwards.

I tried setting the seed and found certain seeds that gave me good results every time whereas most other seeds won't converge for many epochs.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(5)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(42)
```

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: My consists of simulated "out of focus dots" that overlap with each other. The data is simulated and the pattern is very uniform between the datasets. I don't think I need that many. 
Alas, I have 1200 samples, each sample is 16 frames of 256x256 images.

Comment: Then if you have enough data the random split shouldn't be that important...

Comment: It's the random initial weights that are important.

Comment: only if you do a very low amount of epoch with big batches, otherwise the weights converge

Comment: Using a batch size of 2. The loss function doesn't change in the first epoch with most randomly initialized weights.

Comment: well in my opinion it's a weird behaviour and it shouldn't happen. You should take a look at the different kind of initialization of the weights. The most common and used right now is `glorot_normal`aka `Xavier normal initializer`.

Comment: I found out the reason. relu isn't differentiable if the output is negative. Certain random initialized weights could have resulted in the pre-activation function output being excessively negative. Changing the activation function to a differentiable one fixed the issue.